# Selecionar um arquivo por parte do nome em PHP

Tags: php, arquivo

Boa tarde, preciso de uma ajuda para selecionar um arquivo por parte do nome dele em PHP. Utilizo o padrão de nomenclatura iniciando pela data de criação do arquivo no formato: 20160111_ALGUMA_COISA e preciso que o meu PHP selecione apenas o arquivo pela parte até a DATA, ignorando o restante _ALGUMA_COISA.

Alguém pode ajudar com esta parte do código?

Obrigado, no aguardo

Comment: O que você já tentou? Como está seu código agora? Onde especificamente você está tendo problemas?

Comment: Por que não utilizar apenas `strpos` sem regex, nem subtr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando função [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$str = '20160111_ALGUMA_COISA.txt';
echo substr($str, 0, 8); // retorna '20160111'
```

O valor zero é o ponto inicial da string. O valor 8 é o ponto final onde a string será "cortada". Portanto, retornará os 8 primeiros caracteres.

Por quê valor 8? Por dedução lógica, a parte que deseja extrair possuirá sempre 8 caracteres. Claro que não será possível quando chegarmos a um ano com mais de 5 casas. O ano 9999 é o ano limite. Mas pode estar seguro que ninguém vai se importar com o seu código em 1 de Janeiro de 10000.

Comment: Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107755/selecionar-um-arquivo-por-parte-do-nome-em-php/108145#comment224937_108145

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$str = '20160111_ALGUMA_COISA';

echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str,"_ALGUMA_COISA"));

?>
```

Resultado:

> 20160111

EDIT:

Supondo que o nome do arquivo seja formatado da seguinte forma: DATA_ALGUMA_COISA e eu queira retirar o "_ALGUMA_COISA", preciso utilizar uma função que "busque" dentro da minha string com o nome do arquivo, cortando desde o inicio (posição 0) até o index que for encontrado o "_ALGUMA_COISA".

> strpos — Encontra a posição da primeira ocorrência de uma string
>
> substr — Retorna uma parte de uma string

Em linhas curtas, eu "corto" da string o que eu quero, até onde começa a aparecer o que eu **não** quero.

20160111**_ALGUMA_COISA**

A vantagem de utilizar essa abordagem, é que você pode ter qualquer formatacao de data (com N caracteres), que você vai sempre excluir o **_ALGUMA_COISA**.

Comment: Pode explicar o que o código está fazendo?  De preferencia na propria resposta.

Comment: Editado. Dê uma olhada, Diego Felipe :)

Answer (score 2):

Você diz que o padrão é "20160111_ALGUMA_COISA"

Significa que seria (data)*(alguma)*(coisa).

Pode usar isto para obter cada dado:

```
<?php

$nome = '20160111_ALGUMA_COISA'; //nome
$param = explode('_', $nome); //irá dividir cada "_"
$data = $param['0']; // resultará em 20160111.
 //$alguma = $param['1']; 
 //$coisa = $param['2'];

?>
```

*Nota: isto somente irá funcionar se houver _ entre cada parâmetro.*

Se deseja tornar isto uma data "humana" faça isso:

```
<?php

$data = $param['0']; // 20160111 - ver exemplo anterior ou diretamente do $nome;
$ano = substr($data, 0, 4); // 2016 - corta até o 4 digito
$mes = substr($data, 4, 6); // 01 - do 4º ao 6º digito
$dia = substr($data, 6, 8); // 11 - do 6º ao 8º digito

$dataHumana = $dia.'/'.$mes.'/'.$ano; // 11/01/2016

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi se você quer buscar os arquivos, ou se eles já estão listados e você quer extrair o numero a frente.

Se quiser extrair o numero pode usar o `explode` assim (desta maneira o explode só irá dividir pelo primeiro underline):

```
<?php
$filename = '20160111_ALGUMA_COISA.txt';
list($id, $name) = explode('_', $filename, 2);

echo 'Id: ', $id, PHP_EOL;
echo 'Nome: ', $name, PHP_EOL;
```

Você também pode usar `strtok`:

```
<?php
$filename = '20160111_ALGUMA_COISA.txt';
$id = strtok($filename, '_');
$name = strtok('');

echo 'Id: ', $id, PHP_EOL;
echo 'Nome: ', $name, PHP_EOL;
```

Se quiser remover a extensão pode usar o `rtrim`, assim:

```
<?php
$filename = '20160111_ALGUMA_COISA.txt';
list($id, $name) = explode('_', $filename, 2);

$name = rtrim($name, '.txt');

echo 'Id: ', $id, PHP_EOL;
echo 'Nome: ', $name, PHP_EOL;
```

Ou:

```
<?php
$filename = '20160111_ALGUMA_COISA.txt';
$id = strtok($filename, '_');
$name = strtok('');

$name = rtrim($name, '.txt');

echo 'Id: ', $id, PHP_EOL;
echo 'Nome: ', $name, PHP_EOL;
```

Agora se o que você deseja é listar os arquivos que começam com números você pode tentar usar o `glob`:

```
<?php
foreach (glob('[0-9]*[_]*.txt') as $filename) {
    echo $filename, '<br>';
}
```

Documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

Com strstr também é possível.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php

```
   <?php
   $filename = '20160111_ALGUMA_COISA.txt';

   //omitindo o terceiro parâmetro - default false-(retornaria _ALGUMA_COISA.txt)
   $newFile  = strstr($filename, '_');
   echo $newFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eduardo Você também pode fazer desta forma

```
 $arquivo = "20160111_ALGUMA_COISA";
 $arquivo  = explode("_", $arquivo);
 $arq1 = trim($arquivo[0]); // 1º
 $arq2 = trim($arquivo[1]); // 2º

 echo $arq1.'<br>';
 echo $arq2;
```

Comment: Boa noite Fabio, o que isto difere do exemplo do @Inkeliz?

Comment: E bem parecido só que usei o "trim" pra corrigir algum espaço em branco

Comment: Acho que o `trim` em nada mudou, se fosse leitura de arquivos de texto aonde existiriam quebras de linha isto funcionaria, aqui não. Ficou a mesma coisa da resposta do @Inkeliz, não me leve a mal é que realmente isto não faz sentido, entenda como uma critica construtiva da sua colaboração no *Stack Overflow em Português* ;)

Answer (score -1):

Pessoal muito interessante as diversas colaborações, mas segue o código final para quem precisar (obrigado):

```
$data = date('Ymd'); //pega data no formato
$str = $data;//cria variavel com a data

$filename = substr($str, 0, 8);//ajusta para identificar a parte inicial do arquivo
echo "<br>Localizar arquivo iniciado em:   $filename  <br>";

$iterator = new DirectoryIterator('E:/xampp/htdocs/LAB/diretorio'); 

foreach ( $iterator as $entry ) {//executa o loop

$nome = $entry->getFilename();//busca o registro com o nome da data
echo "nome:  $nome";
$certo = substr($nome, 0, 8);

if($certo == $filename){
   echo " ---->> O arquivo $certo existe<br>-----------------<br><br>";
   copy($nome, "encerradas/$nome");//faz copia de segurança
   copy("figuraencerrada.jpg", $nome);//copia o arquivo padrao
    echo " Arquivo $certo copiado com segurança<br>-----------------<br><br>";
} 
else {
   echo "    Nenhum arquivo foi localizado com o este nome $certo<br>-----------------<br>";
}
}
```

Comment: Esta é praticamente a reposta do @DanielOmine a única coisa que você fez foi adicionar o código que já estava usando e que você não especificou na pergunta. Entenda, não somos uma fórum somos um Q&A. Se a resposta do Daniel é a correta então você deveria marcar ela. Entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)